# How to get airport tax refund of unused flight with Wizzair 2 years ago?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, tax-refunds, wizz-air

I just managed to get refunds from AirBaltic this year. I however noticed that I have some unused flights, the oldest 2 years ago with [Wizzair](https://wizzair.com/en-GB/information-and-services/prices-discounts/refunds-and-compensations#/). 
I can't find any email address I can contact the company with about the refunds -- they only offer *Contact as* as Premium service [here](https://wizzair.com/en-gb/information-and-services/contact/contact-us#/):

> Wizz Air’s Call Centre is accessible through premium rate numbers.

I am wondering what the longest timeframe is to apply for those refunds.

Assuming 2 years is still valid time period, how can you proceed with Wizzair?

Comment: You ring them - thats why they are a low cost carrier, you get charged for stuff like talking to them.

Comment: @Moo And ringing them is more expensive than 20 euros. Right? I do not want to ring them but just send them enquiry to get the refund.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Legal postal adress of them:
Wizz Air Hungary Ltd. Laurus Offices | Kőér u. 2./A | B épület | H-1103 | Budapest, Magyarország. info@wizzair.com.

They will deny any refund of taxes as they violate already EU1008/2008 concerning showing them up in the confirmations.

You may write a complaint to the Civil aviation authority of Hungary, but they ignore and cover any action of Wizz.(https://www.nkh.gov.hu/web/english/aviation)

After you may complaint to the european commission concerning violation of regulatories by the Civil....they also dont want to work and rejecting because of planned amendments to 1008/2008.

So, at least you may just go to a hungarian civil court,if Wizz denies, as they smartly didnt opened any office in another countries to kick out their legal clause for applicable hungarian law.

Comment: I will call the commission telephone number. I let you know how it goes.

Comment: I called the commission, and waiting for the instructions to make the complaint on the case. It will take years for the complaint resolution, but that is fine. - - Can you state any evidence that Civil Authority of Hungary is ignoring complaints of such cases?

Answer (score 2):

Wizz Air alone does not refund them, here is the excerpt from their Conditions of Carriage

7.2.Taxes, Charges and Fees for Other Services
7.2.1. The Fare generally includes taxes, fees and charges imposed by governments, other authorities or by airport operators on Wizz Air effective on the date of issue of the Itinerary and the lowest amount of unavoidable Fees for Other Services that are necessary for making the reservation at the levels effective at the time of reservation and purchase. The passenger-based airport charges included in
the Fare are the consideration for the services provided by the operator of the airport to You, covering the handling of passengers and baggage in the territory of the airport, including but not limited to passenger and baggage check-in, passenger security check, baggage security screening, passport control and boarding. Any taxes and charges imposed by an airport operator, even if they are based on the number of passengers, are not refundable.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the airport tax refunded on Wizz, is for flights departing or arriving in Germany. Again, you can't or they'll just ignore you.

I've used a website from Germany specialised in this (google it: Geld fuer Flug). It takes just 2min to fill in the request, and they will get back to you if it's successfull or not (1-2days from personal experience). They don't specially exactley (they'll take their comission from the tax, around 20-30% probably).

The only downside that they don't specify on their FAQ, even though you sign that you agree with their terms from you mobile (when accepting the offer they make you), they still need to send you the papers for you to sign (transfering the ownership of the airfare tickets from from you to them). And they only send those papers in Germany, Austria or Switzerland (they provide for envelops, stamps all the thing required to send them back). So if you're living there, or have someone living there, they can assist you with this ;)

You can go back for the last 3 years to ask for the refund.